# Evaluating $\int_a^b\frac{e^{-x}}{x} \,\mathrm dx$.

Tags: calculus, integration

How can one evaluate $\int_a^b\frac{e^{-x}}{x} \,\mathrm dx$?

I tried using integration by parts, but it did not work.

Comment: There is no elementary antiderivative. Where did this show up that you expect an "answer"?

Comment: There is a "special function" invented to stand for this... $$\int\frac{e^{-x}}{x}\;dx = -\operatorname{Ei}_1(x)$$

Comment: [Here](https://socratic.org/questions/how-do-you-integrate-e-x-x-dx#405475) is the answer for GEdgar's solution.

Comment: Assuming $a$ and $b$ are nonzero and equal in sign we have $\int_a^b e^{-x}/x\,\mathrm dx=\left(\int_a^\infty-\int_b^\infty\right) x^{0-1}e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx=\Gamma(0,a)-\Gamma(0,b)$, with $\Gamma(\alpha,z)$ denoting the upper incomplete gamma function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no elementary antiderivative but an answer is possible...

\begin{align*}\int_{a}^{b}{e^{-x}\over x}& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{(-1)^{n}\over n!}\int_{a}^{b}x^{n-1}dx
\\ & =\int_{a}^{b}{1\over x}dx + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over n!}\int_{a}^{b}x^{n-1}dx
\\ & =\ln\left({b\over a}\right)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n\over n\cdot n!}(b^n-a^n)
\end{align*}